# How to use OData in a table with many-to-many relationship and without a primary key

Tags: c#, api, odata

I have a table with many-to-many relationship:

```
public class ServiceEquipment
{
    [ForeignKey("Service")]
    public long ServiceRef { get; set; }
    public Service Service { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Equipment")]
    public long EquipmentRef { get; set; }
    public Equipment Equipment { get; set; }
}
```

I use the following EDM model for OData:

```
static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new();
    .
    .
    .
    builder.EntitySet<ServiceEquipment>("ServiceEquipments");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

The following is my controller for OData:

```
public class ServiceEquipmentsController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly SqlServerContext _sqlServerContext;

        public ServiceEquipmentsController(SqlServerContext sqlServerContext)
        {
            _sqlServerContext = sqlServerContext;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<ServiceEquipment> Get()
        {
            IQueryable<ServiceEquipment> srEqList = _sqlServerContext.ServiceEquipment.AsQueryable();

            return srEqList;
        }
    }
```

When I run the code, there is an error in line `builder.EntitySet<ServiceEquipment>("ServiceEquipments");` of the EDM and says:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity set 'ServiceEquipments'
> is based on type 'ArtaNG_API.Models.ServiceEquipment' that has no keys
> defined.'

Is there any way to use OData on this table?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem by adding `[key]` attribute to the `public long ServiceRef { get; set; }`.